# Excel VBA: How to turn formulas into values for the last used column?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to turn all my formulas into values for the last used column in my sheet. (Last column changes monthly) This is my code so far:

```
Sub turnvalues2()
Set rng = Range(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1` returns a number not a range.  You want the Columns() at that number.

```
Sub turnvalues2()
Set rng = Columns(Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1)
rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Also the `- 1` moves it to the second to last column used,  You may want to remove that to get the last column used.

Comment: when I used the code, I got "Runtime error 1004: Method 'range' of Object_'Global' failed"

Comment: also, I did it without the -1 and still got the same error

Comment: Change `Range` to `Cells` and that will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Alternate version using Range.Find to get last populated column:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rFound = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then rFound.EntireColumn.Value = rFound.EntireColumn.Value

End Sub
```